# Some confusion in a solution to Leetcode NQueen

Tags: java, arraylist, depth-first-search

```
public class Solution {

Set<Integer> column = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> diag1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> diag2 = new HashSet<Integer>();

public List<List<String>> solveNQueens(int n) {
    ArrayList<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    dfs(result, list, 0, n);
    return result;
}

private void dfs(ArrayList<List<String>> result, ArrayList<String> list,
        int row, int n) {
    if (row == n) {
        result.add(new ArrayList<String>(list)); 
        // Why I have to "result.add(new ArrayList<String>(list))"?
        // Why can't I just "result.add(list)"?

        return;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (column.contains(j) || diag1.contains(row + j)
                || diag2.contains(row - j))// check if there are other
                                            // queens in the same column,
                                            // diagonal1 or diagonal2
            continue;


        char[] rowChar = new char[n];
        Arrays.fill(rowChar, '.');
        rowChar[j] = 'Q';
        String str = new String(rowChar);

        list.add(str);
        column.add(j);
        diag1.add(row + j);
        diag2.add(row - j);

        dfs(result, list, row + 1, n);

        // remove the queen and the constraints
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
        column.remove(j);
        diag1.remove(row + j);
        diag2.remove(row - j);
    }

}
```

It's an N-Queens problem in Leetcode. I found a solution to the problem but I have a question which I have commented in the code. 
Why I have to "result.add(new ArrayList(list))"?
Why can't I just "result.add(list)"? 
Since when I use "result.add(list)", the result is not correct. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Since result.add(list) only add the reference of list to result. When the content of list change, the added things in the result will also change. So result.add(new ArrayList(list)) is needed.